# Interchange of integral and derivative

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, measure-theory

I want to show for all $t\in \mathbb R$: 
$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{\mathbb R} e^{-x^4 + tx^2}dx = \int_{\mathbb R}x^2e^{-x^4+tx^2}dx$$
Now once we justified the interchange of the differential operator and the integral it's easy to see.
Obviously $x \mapsto e^{-x^4 + tx^2} $ is differentiable for all $t\in \mathbb R$.
But I can't seem to find a suitable dominating integrable function $f(x)$ satisfying $$\forall t\in \mathbb R: \left \lvert \frac{\partial}{\partial t} e^{-x^4 + tx^2}\right \rvert = \left \lvert x^2 e^{-x^4 + tx^2}\right \rvert \leq f(x)$$
I assume we can split this into compact intervals and get an estimate for each fixed $t_0 \in \mathbb R$, but then our $f(x)$ depends on $t$. Any hints?

Comment: Maybe use $x^2 \leq e^{x^2}$, so $|x^2e^{-x^4+tx^2}|\leq |e^{x^2-x^4+tx^2}| = e^{-x^4+(t+1)x^2}$? This is asymptotically $e^{-x^2}$, so it's integrable over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I still need an upper bound independent of $t$.

Comment: Don't you only need a uniform-in-$t$ bound _locally_ in $t$? That is, doesn't it suffice to consider, e.g., $t\in[-N,N]$ for fixed $N$?

Comment: I assume it does. Apparently you only need a uniform bound within some interval around each $t $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A useful trick is to turn differentiation problems into integration problems. For example, in this case,
$$
         \int_{t_0}^{t}\int_{\mathbb{R}}x^2e^{-x^4+sx^2}dxds=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{t_0}^{t}x^2e^{-x^2+sx^2}dsdx \\
      = \left.\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-x^4+sx^2}\right|_{s=t_0}^{t}dx \\
      = \int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-x^4+tx^2}dx+C,
$$
where $C$ is a constant that does not depend on $t$. In order to invoke the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, all you have to do is argue that the following is a continuous function of $s$:
$$
       \int_{\mathbb{R}}x^2e^{-x^4+sx^2}dx
$$
Then the desired result follows by differentiating both sides of the first equation with respect to $t$. The conclusion is that the right side of the first equation is a continuously differentiable in $t$, and the derivative is
$$
      \int_{\mathbb{R}}x^2e^{-x^2+tx^2}dx
$$

Comment: Nice solution, however I may not use theorems like Fubini for this exercise.